# Adding/Removing border to TR using JQuery

Tags: jquery

Please see the following JSFiddle: [**JSFiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/2EmmK/)

My JQuery:

```
$('.tr1').addClass('addBorder');
$('.tr2').removeClass('removeBorder');

$('#bName').click(function() {
    $('.tr1').addClass('addBorder');
    $('.tr2').addClass('removeBorder'); 
});
$('#bSpecialty').click(function() {
    $('.tr2').addClass('addBorder');
    $('.tr1').addClass('removeBorder'); 
});
```

It is suppose to make the BY NAME row have double blue border and based on the user selection from the radio button should make that row have the blue border and remove the border from the row that is not selected. It's not working for some reason.

I tried `toggleClass();` but that removes the existing class, which won't work as the user should be able to click on the same radio button multiple times and the class should not change. It should only change if the other radio button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add border to table cell not the row. Also you don't need to add two different class.. instead you can just `addClass` that adds border and `removeClass` on the other. See DEMO:  **http://jsfiddle.net/XZ5eg/**

```
$(function () {
    var $rowName = $('.tr1 td');
    var $rowSpeciality = $('.tr2 td');

    $rowName.addClass('addBorder');
    $rowSpeciality.removeClass('removeBorder');

    $('#bName').click(function() {
        $rowName.addClass('addBorder');
        $rowSpeciality.removeClass('addBorder');    
    });
    $('#bSpecialty').click(function() {
        $rowSpeciality.addClass('addBorder');
        $rowName.removeClass('addBorder');  
    });

});
```

Comment: What I was looking to do, you helped me. I can actually use the TR to add the class.

Comment: I agree with just having one class. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also you should remove the class "removeBorder" from the table-cells, otherwise you will have both 'addBorder' and 'removeBorder' on that element.

```
$('#bName').click(function() {
    $('.tr1 td').removeClass('removeBorder');
    $('.tr1 td').addClass('addBorder');
    $('.tr2 td').addClass('removeBorder');  
});
$('#bSpecialty').click(function() {
    $('.tr2 td').removeClass('removeBorder');
    $('.tr2 td').addClass('addBorder');
    $('.tr1 td').addClass('removeBorder');  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this what you need:

```
$('.tr1 td').addClass('addBorder');
$('#bName,#bSpecialty').click(function () {
    $('td').toggleClass('removeBorder, addBorder ');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2EmmK/14/)**

Comment: @Vega did what I wanted to do, but yours works just as same. Thanks :)